# I want add digital signature in my dynamic pdf with using itext sharp and in signature insert acrofield

Tags: c#, pdf, model-view-controller, itext

I was trying to insert textfield in digtal signature with using itextsharp but not able to insert that text in esignature.

My code please check Also I want verify that signature still not able to do this code any suggestion would be appriciate..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KGOn.jpg

```
public void Sign(string SigReason, string SigContact, string SigLocation, bool visible)
{
    string password = @"123";
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.inputPDF,new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(password));
    //Activate MultiSignatures
    PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), '\0', null, true);
    //To disable Multi signatures uncomment this line : every new signature will invalidate older ones !
    //PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), '\0'); 
    //string pdfTemplate = Server.MapPath("~/Data/PADForm.pdf");
    //string newFile = Server.MapPath("~/Data/newFile.pdf");

    //signPdfFile(sourceDocument, destinationPath, stream, "123", "testing", "testing");
    //PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate, new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(password));
    //PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create));
    string imageURL = @"C:\Users\amitrs\Desktop\FSI SS\204-25.png";
    iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURL);
   // Resize image depend upon your need
    jpg.ScaleToFit(140f, 120f);
    //Give space before image

    jpg.SpacingBefore = 10f;

    //Give some space after the image

    jpg.SpacingAfter = 1f;

    jpg.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    AcroFields pdfFormFields = st.AcroFields;
    pdfFormFields.SetField("DigitalSignature", "Amit");
    pdfFormFields.SetField("Signature", "Amit Saini");
    st.MoreInfo = this.metadata.getMetaData();
    st.XmpMetadata = this.metadata.getStreamedMetaData();
    PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;
   
    
    sap.SetCrypto(this.myCert.Akp, this.myCert.Chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.VERISIGN_SIGNED);
    sap.Reason = SigReason;
    sap.Contact = SigContact;
    sap.Location = SigLocation;            
    if (visible)
        sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 300), 1, null);
    
    st.Close();
}
```

Comment: An integrated digital PDF signature is already in an AcroForm field, its appearance already is a Form field widget. You cannot insert a text field in another field. You could put a separate text field at the same coordinates, though.

Comment: Thanks! for answer,but i want show text in signature how can i do..

Comment: The signature appearance object has a layer 2 text property. Simply set that property to match your requirements.

Comment: Thank you! Its working u have save my whole day..

Comment: Also want add checkbow and when any check checked i apply digital signature in that field  any idea for this..?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTextSharp signature appearance object have 2 property, you have to set property.

```
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;
sap.Layer2Text = "XYZ";
```

Hope this helps